# DataTable Vb.net Create Composite Keys

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, datatable

HI guys i have a table in a database which has no primarykey. I think the reason is its just a table with alot of foreign keys. I dont really know my sql is quite poor. So the table was not created by me but i have problem when creating my datatable. To update my Dataset the table requires a primary key. Since all columns arent unique i would have to make  composite keys. Anyone knows how. Here is the code for create a primary key in the first one.

```
 'after using adapter and all the connection process to fill the dataset

      Dim tableProduct As DataTable = productDataSet.Tables(0)


     tableProduct.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {tableProduct.Columns(0)}
```

And here is me trying to create composite keys

```
            Dim tableProduct As DataTable = productDataSet.Tables(0)


     tableProduct.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {tableProduct.Columns(0)}
       tableProduct.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {tableProduct.Columns(1)}
```

I recently started vb.net previously i worked on java and php  , Jquery and such. so i am not so experience with .Net Framework If i asked the question wrongly pls tell me so i can edit Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly you need to define your table primary key using two (or more) datacolumns. In your code above, you set the PrimaryKey first with one column, then you change this primary key and use a different column. But you Always get a PrimaryKey with only one column.

Try with this

```
tableProduct.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() _
                              {
                                   tableProduct.Columns(0), 
                                   tableProduct.Columns(1)  
                              }
```

See [How to: Initialize an Array Variable in VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y13tek7e.aspx)

Comment: IS there anyways to check which columns are the primarykeys and how many of there? Like msgbox(keycount or something)

Comment: Of course, the PrimaryKey is an array that could also be read. `tableProduct.PrimaryKey.Length` and `for each dc in tableProduct.PrimaryKey` See [MSDN VB Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.primarykey.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: Theres still something wrong but there are now a few keys i guess its just the database thanks!!!!!